# Using method parameters in an interface

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay so, I have to use an interface in a code I'm making involving currency and there are some methods I've created with parameters. Question: Does it matter if I create the my interface class with different parameter names than the classes that are implementing it?

For example:

```
//One of my methods which calculates a US paper currency (created in my interface class)
BigDecimal getUSD(int onepaper, int fiftypaper, int twentypaper,  int tenpaper, int fivepaper, int onepaperval);

//One of my classes which contains the getUSD method in it.
public void getUSD(int dollars, int quarters, 
        int dimes, int nickels, int pennies)
{
    payment = dollars + quarters * QUARTER_VALUE + dimes * DIME_VALUE
            + nickels * NICKEL_VALUE + pennies * PENNY_VALUE;
}
```

Will this create an issue when java runs? (Note this is my first time using interfaces)

Comment: Next time, highlight all of your code an press CTRL + K to make it all one big code block.

Comment: What happens when you ... try it?

Comment: ^ Well I dont't get any error when I use the same name, but I haven't run anything yet so I guess I'll have to let you know should any arise. According to Jeff, there won't be an issue though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what you name your variables as long as they are in the same order and of the same type as the interface.